# Tensorflow's while loop slower than conventional while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, time

Here is a conventional while loop doing a basic add operation -

```
import time
def check(a,b):
 while(a<b):
    a += 1
 return [a,b]

a = 1
b = 1500000
start = time.time()
check(a,b)
print("Time = ",time.time() - start)

Time =  0.07060480117797852
```

Here is the optimized code using Tensorflow -

```
import tensorflow as tf
def cond(t1, t2):
    return tf.less(t1, t2)

def body(t1, t2):
    return [tf.add(t1, 1), t2]

t1 = tf.constant(1)
t2 = tf.constant(1500000)

start = time.time()
res = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [t1, t2], parallel_iterations = 10)
print("Time = ",time.time() - start)

Time =  22.1693217754364
```

Why does the optimized code execute slower than conventional code. I have a GTX GPU with 6GB memory. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't expect that tf.while_loop would be faster than a simple python loop such as

```
for( int i=0; i<1500000; i++)
   j=j+1;
```

Will always perform better in python, javaScript, c, etc.

tensorflow is highly optimized for matrices operation, not for a simple loop.

I know you are just exploring different approach and that is great.

A more tensorflow way would be

```
t1 = tf.constant(1)
t2 = tf.constant(1500000)
start = time.time()
t3 = t1 + t2
print("Time = ",time.time() - start)
```

and on my machine,
Time =  0.0010001659393310547

So, again, tf is a framework for linear algebra operations. If you try to use it as a general language framework, it won't do a great job.

PS. I think i have seen you around here before :-D Happy new year !

Comment: Yep! You helped me earlier too, Happy New Year!

Comment: no no, you helped me to learn a lot. Questions like this one are super cool because it makes us think in a more abstract way. Thank YOU for helping me to learn more !